# AngularJS: Possible to sanitize and linky in same directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I try to filter snippet with linky, the input is no longer sanitized / rendered / 'html-ized'.  i.e. I want to be able to combine the effects of both:

```
<div ng-bind-html="snippet"></div>
```

and

```
<div ng-bind-html="snippet | linky"></div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5uSnj/

Comment: I've played with this for the last 30 mins and it seems like the linky filter does not sanitise HTML tags properly. Many people have complained about it on the talkbalk at angular documentation site.

Tried using $sanitise service, $filter and combination -- referencing the JS script angular-sanitise.js...

Think you're out of luck with using the filter. Perhaps make your own directive?

Comment: Yep, created a new directive to sanitize and linkify.  Here's the pull request, we'll see what devs say: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3285

Comment: I'd be very interested to use this. Has @Igor's snippet been turned into a bower installable script?

Answer (score 1):

linky takes text as input and not html. if you want a filter that takes html as input then it has to work completely differently. please see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3285#issuecomment-21958391

Answer (score 0):

sorry Igor Minar  i voted you answer but i want see post your function without other services :

```
    app.filter('htmlLinky', function($sanitize, linkyFilter) {
  var ELEMENT_NODE = 1;
  var TEXT_NODE = 3;
  var linkifiedDOM = document.createElement('div');
  var inputDOM = document.createElement('div');

  var linkify = function linkify(startNode) {
    var i, ii, currentNode;

    for (i = 0, ii = startNode.childNodes.length; i < ii; i++) {
      currentNode = startNode.childNodes[i];

      switch (currentNode.nodeType) {
        case ELEMENT_NODE:
          linkify(currentNode);
          break;
        case TEXT_NODE:
          linkifiedDOM.innerHTML = linkyFilter(currentNode.textContent);
          i += linkifiedDOM.childNodes.length - 1
          while(linkifiedDOM.childNodes.length) {
            startNode.insertBefore(linkifiedDOM.childNodes[0], currentNode);
          }
          startNode.removeChild(currentNode);
      }
    }

    return startNode;
  };

  return function(input) {
    inputDOM.innerHTML = input;
    return linkify(inputDOM).innerHTML;
  };
});
```

ng-bind-html="html | htmlLinky"